# Geometric Lang conjecture - reference

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

In their paper "Uniformity of rational points", Caporaso, Harris, and Mazur asserted the following:

"The Geometric Lang conjecture has been proved for all surfaces with $c_1^2 > c_2$ ([B]), and has recently been announced for all surfaces ([LM])."

The referece [LM] in that paper (link here: http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1997-10-01/S0894-0347-97-00195-1/S0894-0347-97-00195-1.pdf) is a preprint by S. Lu and M. Miyaoka, with no title. Their paper was published in 1997, so surely this preprint should be published by now, but I am unable to find it. Does anyone know the actual title of the paper, and perhaps what journal it is published in?

Comment: The paper is *Bounding curves in algebraic surfaces by genus and Chern numbers*. Math. Res. Lett. 2 (1995), no. 6, 663-676 (the Caporaso-Harris-Mazur paper was accepted in revised form early 1995). However, Lu and Miyaoka prove only a weak form of the geometric Lang conjecture, namely that there are only finitely many *smooth* rational or elliptic curves on a surface of general type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

abx's comment was made while I was writing this, but I am posting it as an answer anyway.

There has not been a proof of this conjecture of Lang, which remains a wide open problem. Lu and Miyaoka's paper to which Caporaso, Harris and Mazur refer has to be [this one](https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/mrl/1995/0002/0006/MRL-1995-0002-0006-a001.pdf) (*Bounding curves in algebraic surfaces by genus and Chern numbers*, IMRN, 1995) and its sequel cited as [6] in higher dimensions. However, the main result of that paper, cf. Corollary 1 and the announced *Theorem 0*, has actually an (unnatural) smoothness condition on the rational or elliptic curves involved.

For a comparison you may recall that in the arithmetic case, for arithmetic surfaces (algebraic curves), Vojta has proved a weaker form of his conjecture that has an *arithmetic discriminant* term $d_a(P)$ in place of a field discriminant term and which, in contrast to the Vojta conjecture, is far too weak to be adequate for deriving any consequence about the $abc$ conjecture.

A related problem and another partial result on the geometric Lang conjecture can be found in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/173547/generalizations-of-de-franchis-and-function-field-mordell) of mine, and in its answer by Francesco Polizzi.